# Having trouble with functions calling other functions through dictionaries: could someone please explain this code to me?

Tags: python, iterator

This is used in a text-based game to determine if a different room has been entered in order to run a function.  It is learning exercise so I am sure the code is not optimal. The whole thing is started by running the code on the last line.

```
def runner(map, start):
    next = start

    while True:
        room = map[next]
        print "\n--------"
        next = room()

runner(ROOMS, 'central_corridor')
```

Here is the ROOMS dictionary that is being used as a argument in the runner function:

```
ROOMS = {
  'death': death,
  'central_corridor': central_corridor,
  'laser_weapon_armory': laser_weapon_armory,
  'the_bridge': the_bridge,
  'escape_pod': escape_pod
}
```

So, more specifically, my question is how is this while loop being used to run the function of the next room if the next room has been entered within the game? I sense the answer lies with the next iterator contained in the while loop.

Comment: `next` isn't an iterator, it's a string that holds the name of a room. You pass in a room name to `runner`, it looks up the appropriate function in `ROOMS`, assigns it to `room` and then calls it. Each room function must be returning a name which is the next room to go to. I'm assuming each room function - like `central_corrider` - is asking for user input and then returning a name based on that eg `'n'` returns `'laser_weapon_armory'`, `'s'` returns `'the_bridge'` etc.

Comment: Don't use the names `next` and `map` as variables, since they shadow the builtin functions of the same names.

Comment: @moaroN You should also modify the question title as the code you show has nothing to do with generators or iterators.

Comment: @unutbu I am using learnpythonthehard way and he has me using next and map. Are you saying that the builtin functions of both are overwritten by the way they are used? I have been looking those up as a way to understand that and find it unnecessarily confusing. Thanks for clearing that up if that is the case.

Comment: learnpythonthehardway is living up to its name by naming variables `map` and `next`. Grrr!

Comment: @moaroN Incidentally, this technique is known as "dictionary dispatching".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code would be much simpler to understand if we rename the variables. Never name variables `map` or `next` since doing so shadows the builtins of the same name.

Here is what the same code might look like after renaming `map` and `next`:

```
ROOMS = {
  'death': death,
  'central_corridor': central_corridor,
  'laser_weapon_armory': laser_weapon_armory,
  'the_bridge': the_bridge,
  'escape_pod': escape_pod
}


def runner(visit, start):
    room = start

    while True:
        action = visit[room]
        print "\n--------"
        room = action()

runner(ROOMS, 'central_corridor')
```

The `visit` variable is a dict which maps rooms to actions (which are functions). The return value of an action is a room.
So

```
action = visit[room]
```

looks up the action that occurs when you visit a room,
and

```
room = action()
```

sets `room` to the value of the next room after `action` has been performed.